# angular 2 application does not load but I get no errors

Tags: angular, systemjs

When I load my typescript angular 2 test app it does not load as expected.

I always see "Loading..." what is from the my-app in the index html file.

I also get no errors in the bowser console :/

Anyone is seeing the error?

**INDEX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>test</title>
    <script src="~/lib/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/es6-promise.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('app/main')
                  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap, ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
 @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
   // providers: [...FORM_PROVIDERS],
  //  directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterActive],
    pipes: [],
    styles: [],
    template: `   
        <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>       
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
    angularclassLogo = 'assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png';
    name = 'Angular 2 Webpack Starter';
    url = 'https://twitter.com/AngularClass';
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks ok to me.I even tried it on my setup, it's working fine on beta.7 . does your .ts files get compiled to .js ?, also you could put a console.log just before bootstrap(..) in main.ts

Comment: your code seems to be perfact. same as @Abdulrahman you code is working fine on my system. again check your console for loading file properly ?

Comment: I did looked at the console. there is nothing...

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint into your main.ts file from the Source tab of Dev tools in your browser? After reloading the page, processing should pause here. Then you will be able to execute things step by step to try to find out where the problem occurs. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you without anyone error message :-(

Comment: I found the error. I cleared my transpile target folder and recompiled everything then it worked again ?! Odd... Probably I should include my .js target app folder in the .ts compilation...

Answer (score 1):

Try studying the great Angular2 Plunker https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html (TypeScript)

You are using Typescript, but don't have it included in HTML and properly configured in systemjs:

```
// Missing typescript transpiler
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>

<script>
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',                            // <-- missing!
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}   // <-- you have bad extension
});
System.import('app/main')             // <-- main.ts should be inside 'app' folder!
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
...
</script>
```

Also, i don't think it is ok to use tilde `~` character in script's `src` attribute.

**UPDATE**

If you already have your `.ts` code transpiled into `.js`, please make sure that you compiled it with **experimental decorators** enabled - your `tsconfig.json` should be similar to this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should I include typescript in my index.html file? I transpile .ts files to .js files and those .js files got included by systemJS! The tilde is allowed because I use a asp.net .cshtml file.

Comment: That is important piece of imformation I missed in your initial post. Updated my answer with another guess.

Comment: I have this too else I would get a transpile exception (which I already got ;-) ). But I found the error. I cleared my transpile target folder and recompiled everything then it worked again ?! Odd...

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue in my template. I removed Mobx and ng2-mobx from an app, but forgot to remove `*mobxAutorun` from the template. Removing the directive made it work.

(Apparently Angular does not show any errors if they are in the template. This might actually a feature, so that if you have an ngIf that fails, it will just consider that if as false, instead of showing an error. Don't know if it's possible to change this behavior.)